# How to stop Django Rest Framework from rendering html for exceptions

Tags: json, django

I have set `Debug=False` in my settings to test my error handling in my client, but am getting an html payload (`<h1>Server Error (500)</h1>`) from an exception in this api_view:

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
@transaction.atomic()
def process_payment(request):

    # Do some work

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am making the call from AngularJS, using the default Accept headers: `Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*`

The documentation on the [Renderers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) page seems to indicate that I can expect json if I'm explicitly using the json renderer for successful responses.

Is this a side effect of local development? I don't want to have to write code to test for non-json responses if I can help it.

UPDATE

I should have mentioned that I wildcarded `ALLOWED_HOSTS` for this test, so I don't think that is the problem.

Looking through the default error handling in DRF, it looks like any exception that is not either derived from `APIException` or is an `Http404` or `PermissionDenied` will result in a Response=None. This is where I'm seeing the html response, so the solution is probably a Django custom error handler as indicated in the comment below.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129079/returning-json-error-when-catching-django-exception

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to handle this, but by adding the custom DRF exception handler below, an unhandled exception will now have a standard json format.

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # response == None is an exception not handled by the DRF framework in the call above
    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code
    else:
        response = Response({'detail': 'Unhandled server error'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        response.data['status_code'] = 500

        set_rollback()

    return response
```

Answer (score -1):

The error can't in api_view.

This can be a configuration error. Check the configuration files. Check your ALLOWED_HOSTS.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS.